Unable to style the track for @ptomasroos/react-native-multi-slider
I am trying to change the color of the two thumbed Multislider but to not avail. It is stuck at the default color of blue.
I have tried backgroundColor = '#008080',the desired color, but nothing happens. I have also tried all the other color/styling props. I am missing something?
<MultiSlider
    values={sliderValue.map(unscaleValue)}
    min={0}
    max={100}
    onValuesChange={handleValuesChange}
    allowOverlap
    snapped
    step={1} // Step size on the non-linear scale, not actual value step
    trackStyle={{ height: sH * 0.005, backgroundColor: 'green' }}
/>


Here is a picture of what it looks like
Two Thumbed Multislider

Please provide more debugging details

@Danny any leads on this issue ?
